# How to define an anonymous type in python

Tags: python, dynamic, python-2.7

So python is dynamic. I should be able to add attributes to class instances willy-nilly.

I'm trying to do this:

```
spam = None
spam.eggs = []
```

But apparently I can't add an attribute to `None`.

How do I define `spam` as an instance of an undefined 'empty class' to which I can add attributes as I go along?

Comment: No, you can add attributes to object types that *allow it*. `None` and `type` and `int` do not, because they are immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Bag(object):
  pass

spam = Bag()
spam.eggs = []
```

Comment: So I do need to define a class first then?

Comment: Yes. You cannot even add attributes to an instance of `object`.

Comment: What does the `(object)` bit mean? Why not just `class Bag:`?

Comment: It makes sure that `Bag` is a new-style class, which gives many advantages over old-style classes (and is the only style available in 3.x).

Comment: It'll work fine for this without the `(object)` part in both Python 2 & 3.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can add attributes to object types that *allow it*. `None`, `object`, `type`, `int` et. al. do not, because they are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.3+ using [`types.SimpleNamespace`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

spam = SimpleNamespace(eggs=[])
print(spam) # -> namespace(eggs=[])
spam.rice = {}
print(spam) # -> namespace(eggs=[], rice={})
```